# How to convert 1D flattened MNIST Keras to LSTM model without unflattening?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, mnist

I want to change my model architecture a bit on the LSTM so it accepts the same exact flattened inputs the full connected approach does.

### Working Dnn model from Keras examples

```
import keras

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.utils import to_categorical

# import the data
from keras.datasets import mnist

# read the data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

num_pixels = x_train.shape[1] * x_train.shape[2] # find size of one-dimensional vector

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32') # flatten training images
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32') # flatten test images

# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255

# one hot encode outputs
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

num_classes = y_test.shape[1]
print(num_classes)



# define classification model
def classification_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(num_pixels, activation='relu', input_shape=(num_pixels,)))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))


    # compile model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


# build the model
model = classification_model()

# fit the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=10, verbose=2)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

### Same problem but trying LSTM (syntax error still)

```
def kaggle_LSTM_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    # What does return_sequences=True do?
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,
             metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model_kaggle_LSTM = kaggle_LSTM_model()

# fit the model
model_kaggle_LSTM.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=10, verbose=2)

# evaluate the model
scores = model_kaggle_LSTM.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

Problem is here:

```
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
```

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_17: expected
>   ndim=3, found ndim=2

If I go back and don't flatten x_train and y_train, it works. However, I'd like this to be "just another model choice" that feeds off the same pre-processed input. I thought passing shape[1:] would work as that it the real flattened input_shape. I'm sure it's something easy I'm missing about the dimensionality, but I couldn't get it after an hour of twiddling and debugging, although did figure out not flattening the 28x28 to 784 works, but I don't understand why it works. Thanks a lot!

For bonus points, an example of how to do either DNN or LSTM in either 1D (784,) or 2D (28, 28) would be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RNN layers such as LSTM are meant for sequence processing (i.e. a series of vectors which their order of appearance matters). You can look at an image from top to bottom, and consider each row of pixels as a vector. Therefore, the image would be a sequence of vectors and can be fed to the RNN layer. Therefore, according to this description, you should expect that the RNN layer take an input of shape `(sequence_length, number_of_features)`. That's why when you feed the images to the LSTM network in their original shape, i.e. `(28,28)`, it works.

Now if you insist on feeding the LSTM model the flattened image, i.e. with shape `(784,)`, you have at least two options: either you can consider this as a sequence of length one, i.e. `(1, 748)`, which does not make much sense; or you can add a `Reshape` layer to your model to reshape back the input to its original shape suitable for the input shape of a LSTM layer, like this:

```
from keras.layers import Reshape

def kaggle_LSTM_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Reshape((28,28), input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
    # the rest is the same...
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!